# Asked question, I answered it myself, not sure answer has any value, though

Tags: support, specific-question, self-answer

I asked this question yesterday: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28700824/4015623). It got pretty long as I was probably not explaining well.

It turns out the answer didn't have much to do with the question, or at least how I tried to ask it. I posted my answer, but I'm not sure whether to accept it. I'm not sure whether it has a lot to do with my question, but it may, I may be too close to it.

What should I do? Should I mark my own answer as accepted?

Comment: You could edit your original question, to match the answer better.

Comment: Given that you already have your answer, the key question is **will others find it useful** (both in terms of *will they find it* and *is it useful*!) If not, because the question doesn't align well with the answer or it turned out that it was a very specific problem, then you should either delete the question or update the question accordingly and accept your own answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm wondering if I should ask a new question, because I know what the real problem is now. If I edit the original question, I won't get an answer that I need for what the question really is, would I? Since I answered it myself?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I guess that's the thing. Will anyone find it useful. The question I have now is as a result of the comments and answers, but is it different enough to require a new question? I'm finding myself in a catch-22 in my code, and I'm still confused about what to do.

Comment: @pixelmeow I didn't go there when I wrote my comment. Your concerns of editing it are entitled, as an edit would invalidate the other answers given to your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, that's true, too. I hadn't specifically thought of that, but you're right.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to post a link to a new question in my answer, since it is related enough that it might help?

Comment: @pixelmeow _"Would it be acceptable to post a link ..."_ sure.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. The problem came up mysteriously out of nowhere after working for weeks, now it may have gone away just as mysteriously. The operating systems were automatically updated last night and the computers rebooted, maybe that kicked something back into line? That's scary... We'll see how the day goes as to whether I ask a new question. Should I put together what's in these comments as an answer to this question? They did help.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I want to go ahead and delete the question since it now has a down vote. Should I bother moderators with this, since it has answers, or just let it go?

Comment: @pixelmeow you won't be able to delete it yourself - see e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: @jonrsharpe do I worry about this, or get a moderator to delete it? It doesn't matter to me unless it's not worth keeping.